# Switch video subtitles with ExoPlayer while a video is still playing

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, exoplayer

Let's say I have two subtitles for a video, how do you switch an exoplayer's subtitles while the video is playing without resetting the player itself? Like for an example when a user click a button

By following the [exoplayer documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/media-items.html), my current implementation is like this:

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
    val k = player.currentPosition // Get the latest player's current position
    subtitle = SubtitleConfiguration.Builder(newSubtitleUri)
        .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP)
        .setSelectionFlags(C.SELECTION_FLAG_DEFAULT)
        .build()
    mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri(videoUri)
        .setSubtitleConfigurations(ImmutableList.of(subtitle))
        .build()
    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
    player.prepare()
    player.seekTo(k) // seek to the latest position, if we don't do this it would just play back to the beginning of the video
}
```

This has a downside, for once the player would show a black screen for a split second and return to the latest player position. I want to change the subtitle without repreparing the video, so the subtitle switching can be seamless and it wouldn't lead to the split-second black screen I was referring about.

[This GitHub issue post](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5509) tells me that exoplayer doesn't support this currently. But hey, if YouTube could do it, why couldn't I?